# Convert Javascript code to PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying to convert this javascript code to php but I'm confused with the indexof and substring in javascript, I can't seem to work my way to converting the code to php. If anyone could at least help or guide into converting this code. I would really appreciate it.

Below is the javascript code

```
var location = 'N1433.704483,E12100.012501';
  var latlngarr = location[1].split(",");
  if(latlngarr){
   longitude = latlngarr[0]; //经度
   if(longitude.indexOf("E") >= 0){
    longitude = longitude.substring(1);
    var degree = longitude / 100 | 0;  //除100后取整。
    var cent = (longitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
    longitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
   }else if(longitude.indexOf("W") >= 0){
    longitude = longitude.substring(1);
    var degree = longitude / 100 | 0;  //除100后取整。
    var cent = (longitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
    longitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
   }
   latitude = latlngarr[1];//纬度
   if(latitude.indexOf("N") >= 0){
    latitude = latitude.substring(1);
    var degree = latitude / 100 | 0;  //除100后取整。
    var cent = (latitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
    latitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
   }else if(latitude.indexOf("S") >= 0){
    latitude = latitude.substring(1);
    var degree = latitude / 100 | 0;  //除100后取整。
    var cent = (latitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
    latitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
   }
  }
```

Comment: `javascript->client side coding`



`PHP->server side coding`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? They're completely different types of code used for different reasons

Comment: read the documentation for `strpos()` and `substr()`

Comment: I have already read the documentation. I just got all confused. I'm a newbie. I hope you could all can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
longitude.indexOf("E") >= 0
```

With:

```
strpos($longitude, 'E') !== FALSE
```

And:

```
longitude = longitude.substring(1);
```

With:

```
$longitude = substr($longitude, 1);
```

Just change the variables for other occurrences.

This uses [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)